# Focus-Within Working for chrome but not for firefox

Tags: html, css, firefox

I have a small Focus selector for radio buttons on a form for every page that have varying colors depending on the page, It works fine in chrome but not in firefox.

```
#wedo-contact .frm_radio:focus-within{
    background-color:#D81B2D!important;
}


#wedo-contact .frm_radio:-moz-focus-inner{
    background-color:#D81B2D!important;
    outline:none!important;
}
```

```
<div id="frm_field_18_container" class="frm_form_field form-field  frm_top_container horizontal_radio">
    <div id="field_yhi3q_label" class="frm_primary_label">I would like to talk to you about
        <span class="frm_required"></span>
    </div>
    <div class="frm_opt_container" aria-labelledby="field_yhi3q_label" role="group">        <div class="frm_radio" id="frm_radio_18-0"><label for="field_yhi3q-0">      <input type="radio" name="item_meta[18]" id="field_yhi3q-0" value="WEB DESIGN &amp; DEVELOPMENT" data-invmsg="I would like to talk to you about is invalid"> WEB DESIGN &amp; DEVELOPMENT</label></div>
        <div class="frm_radio" id="frm_radio_18-1"><label for="field_yhi3q-1">      <input type="radio" name="item_meta[18]" id="field_yhi3q-1" value="APP DESIGN &amp; DEVELOPMENT" data-invmsg="I would like to talk to you about is invalid"> APP DESIGN &amp; DEVELOPMENT</label></div>
        <div class="frm_radio" id="frm_radio_18-2"><label for="field_yhi3q-2">      <input type="radio" name="item_meta[18]" id="field_yhi3q-2" value="SOCIAL MEDIA" data-invmsg="I would like to talk to you about is invalid"> SOCIAL MEDIA</label></div>
        <div class="frm_radio" id="frm_radio_18-3"><label for="field_yhi3q-3">      <input type="radio" name="item_meta[18]" id="field_yhi3q-3" value="DIGITAL STRATEGY" data-invmsg="I would like to talk to you about is invalid"> DIGITAL STRATEGY</label></div>
        <div class="frm_radio" id="frm_radio_18-4"><label for="field_yhi3q-4">      <input type="radio" name="item_meta[18]" id="field_yhi3q-4" value="360º CAMPAIGN STRATEGY" data-invmsg="I would like to talk to you about is invalid"> 360º CAMPAIGN STRATEGY</label></div>
        <div class="frm_radio" id="frm_radio_18-5"><label for="field_yhi3q-5">      <input type="radio" name="item_meta[18]" id="field_yhi3q-5" value="PACKAGING" data-invmsg="I would like to talk to you about is invalid"> PACKAGING</label></div>
        <div class="frm_radio" id="frm_radio_18-6"><label for="field_yhi3q-6">      <input type="radio" name="item_meta[18]" id="field_yhi3q-6" value="PRINT MEDIA" data-invmsg="I would like to talk to you about is invalid"> PRINT MEDIA</label></div>
        <div class="frm_radio" id="frm_radio_18-7"><label for="field_yhi3q-7">      <input type="radio" name="item_meta[18]" id="field_yhi3q-7" value="ACTIVATIONS" data-invmsg="I would like to talk to you about is invalid"> ACTIVATIONS</label></div>
        <div class="frm_radio" id="frm_radio_18-8"><label for="field_yhi3q-8">      <input type="radio" name="item_meta[18]" id="field_yhi3q-8" value="COPYWRITING" data-invmsg="I would like to talk to you about is invalid"> COPYWRITING</label></div>
        <div class="frm_radio" id="frm_radio_18-9"><label for="field_yhi3q-9">      <input type="radio" name="item_meta[18]" id="field_yhi3q-9" value="GOOGLE ADWORDS" data-invmsg="I would like to talk to you about is invalid"> GOOGLE ADWORDS</label></div>
        <div class="frm_radio" id="frm_radio_18-10"><label for="field_yhi3q-10">        <input type="radio" name="item_meta[18]" id="field_yhi3q-10" value="PHOTOGRAPHY" data-invmsg="I would like to talk to you about is invalid"> PHOTOGRAPHY</label></div>
        <div class="frm_radio" id="frm_radio_18-11"><label for="field_yhi3q-11">        <input type="radio" name="item_meta[18]" id="field_yhi3q-11" value="VIDEOGRAPHY" data-invmsg="I would like to talk to you about is invalid"> VIDEOGRAPHY</label></div>
        <div class="frm_radio" id="frm_radio_18-12"><label for="field_yhi3q-12">        <input type="radio" name="item_meta[18]" id="field_yhi3q-12" value="SEO" data-invmsg="I would like to talk to you about is invalid"> SEO</label></div>
        <div class="frm_radio" id="frm_radio_18-13"><label for="field_yhi3q-13">        <input type="radio" name="item_meta[18]" id="field_yhi3q-13" value="ANIMATION" data-invmsg="I would like to talk to you about is invalid"> ANIMATION</label></div>
        <div class="frm_radio" id="frm_radio_18-14"><label for="field_yhi3q-14">        <input type="radio" name="item_meta[18]" id="field_yhi3q-14" value="ICONOGRAPHY" data-invmsg="I would like to talk to you about is invalid"> ICONOGRAPHY</label></div>
        <div class="frm_radio" id="frm_radio_18-15"><label for="field_yhi3q-15">        <input type="radio" name="item_meta[18]" id="field_yhi3q-15" value="ILLUSTRATION" data-invmsg="I would like to talk to you about is invalid"> ILLUSTRATION</label></div>
        <div class="frm_radio" id="frm_radio_18-16"><label for="field_yhi3q-16">        <input type="radio" name="item_meta[18]" id="field_yhi3q-16" value="CONTENT CREATION" data-invmsg="I would like to talk to you about is invalid"> CONTENT CREATION</label></div>
</div>


</div>
```

Anything im missing thats required for firefox? I can't find to much information on this

My Firefox version:

[image]

Comment: Is your firefox too old? Apparently it's not supported on firefox 51 and older. https://caniuse.com/#search=focus-within

Comment: I also thought that so I updated and asked my manager to check its apparently the same thing for him

Comment: What version of FF are you using?

Comment: 77.0b3 added a screenshot if you dont want to take my word for it

Comment: I thought the bug was with Chrome. I want Firefox and Safari's behaviour where focus-within only works with the keyboard and not the mouse. I haven't found a way to make Chrome behave like Firefox and Safari on this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems to be related to behavior on Firefox Mac (Safari also) and radio input focus: https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=756028

A solution found by Roman Komarov is to use tabindex: https://www.kizu.ru/keyboard-only-focus/#x

```
<div class="frm_radio" id="frm_radio_18-0" tabindex="0">
  <label for="field_yhi3q-0" tabindex="-1">
    <input type="radio" name="item_meta[18]" id="field_yhi3q-0" value="WEB DESIGN &amp; DEVELOPMENT" data-invmsg="I would like to talk to you about is invalid" />
    WEB DESIGN &amp; DEVELOPMENT
  </label>
</div>
```

Comment: Awesome Thanks a million! this did it for me